# Formatting PivotChart Series

Tags: vba, excel, enumeration, pivot-chart

I have a pivot chart and I'm trying to format certain dataseries in my chart with a pattern. I recorded a macro to see how Excel would do that. This gave me:

```
With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .Patterned msopatternDarkUpwardDiagonal
End With
```

Which I've adapted to:

```
With chrt1Overview 'chart object codename
    (....)
    With .FullSeriesCollection(i) 'iterating through series
        .ChartType = xlColumnStacked
        If .Name Like "FORECAST" Then
            With .Format.Fill
                .Visible = msoTrue
                .Patterned msoPatternDarkUpwardDiagonal
            End With
        End If
    End with
End with
```

This gives me the error below and highlights both `msoTrue` and `msoPatternDarkupwardDiagonal` in my code

> Compile error:
>
> Variable not defined

Running the macro as created by the recorder does not work either, the `mso` "variables" are empty and gives an error that the specified value is out of range but does not give me a compile error because the `Option Explicit` is not set on this module.

What is the correct way to set a pattern fill on a data series?

Comment: Google `Enum msoTrue` and `Enum msoPatternDarkUpwardDiagonal` to find out the values, then just replace using the values.

Comment: That's what you get for writing tired; I could not, for the life of me, figure this out. Thanks @braX